# Ethylene Glycol in Wall Primer

Tags: organic-chemistry, inorganic-chemistry, physical-chemistry, everyday-chemistry, biochemistry

No scientific background here!

Due to a chemical sensitivity, and general concern for healthier indoor air quality in a home I am renovating, I opted to choose "greener" alternatives in terms of building materials as I do have a toddler at home. Unfortunately, the primer that was used on our walls, albeit low VOC (11.4g/L), it does contain a solvent.... ethylene glycol. EG is a pretty nasty chemical if what I have researched is correct.

Based on my limited knowledge, EG is a slow evaporating solvent. My concern is how long it will linger even after the primer dries. Generally, I know the expected cure time is 2-4 weeks. With this particular ingredient, from a scientific/chemist point of view, how long will EG take to evaporate, and will exposure to it be ongoing after the "curing" period? If so, approximately for how long, or is it infinite? Thanks!

Comment: While ethylene glycol is really bad to drink, it is hard to inhale enough to cause health effects unless you have lots of open liquid around. The Derived No Effects Level (DNEL) for consumers is 7mg per cubic meter. Given the slow evaporation rate it will prove hard to reach anywhere near such levels with any reasonable air flow.

Comment: Thank you Jon. I'm assuming that it will also, after said amount of time, evaporate and dissipate as well, regardless of slow evaporative rate or not....thanks for your response!